# How to resize an image loaded using ContentManager in XNA

Tags: xna-4.0

I am new to XNA programming and I loaded the background image using ContentManager as a Texture2D object.

The background image which I have is of size 480*320. I have kept the minimum game window size as 640*480. My question is how would i resize the background image to the size of the game window.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever size the destination rectangle is for any of the top 3 [SpriteBatch.Draw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196426.aspx) functions is how large your image will appear on screen.

So try the below to automatically draw an image full screen.

```
SpriteBatch.Draw(background_texture, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds, Color.White);
```

Note this doesn't actually change the size of you image it just scales it to the specified size when rendered.

Comment: Wow that was a simple thing to do. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of XNA :)